# C and C++ linkage with extern "C"

Tags: c++, c, extern, linkage

I have a C++ function defined in a .h file as follows and implemented in a .cpp file:

```
extern "C" void func(bool first, float min, float* state[6], float* err[6][6])
{
    //uses vectors and classes and other C++ constructs
}
```

How can I call func in a C file? How do I set up my file architecture / makefile to compile this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the function *defined* in the header (i.e., including the part between `{  }`), or is it *declared* in the header (i.e., ending with `);`)? If it's the former, you need to write another header file that omits the `extern "C"` and `{  }` part, and use *that* for the C part of your program.

Comment: I do not think I explained my question clearly enough. I will try with better examples.

Comment: I am going to delete and repost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To call it in C, all you need to do is call it normally. Because you told the compiler to use the C calling conventions and ABI with `extern "C"`, you can call it normally:

```
func(args);
```

To compiler, use this for the C++:

```
g++ -c -o myfunc.o myfunc.cpp
```

Then this for the C:

```
gcc -c -o main.o somec.c
```

Than link:

```
g++ -o main main.o myfunc.o
```

Make sure that the C++ header for the function uses **ONLY C CONSTRUCTS**. So include things like `<vector>` in the `.cpp` file instead.

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus: The `-c` option tells the compiler to only compile your code to intermediate object code files (`.o`) which can then be linked together into an executable by excluding the `-c` option. Object files allow you to combine C and C++, and impose some separation into different parts of the project. They also allow you to compile only small parts of your code, which is crucial to large projects and systems like make.

Comment: Thanks! When I run the last compile line (gcc -o main main.o myfunc.o) it fails and tells me I have an undefined reference to files I included in myfunc.cpp

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus: To what files? What is the *exact* message?

Answer (score 11):

You call the function from C in the normal way.  However, you need to wrap the `extern "C"` in an preprocessor macro to prevent the C compiler from seeing it:

```
#ifndef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
void func(bool first, float min, float* state[6], float* err[6][6]);
```

Assuming you're working with GCC, then compile the C code with `gcc`, compile the C++ code with `g++`, and then link with `g++`.

Comment: I am getting erros from gcc saying cannot include vector since my  C file is including the file where func is defined which uses vectors

Comment: You might just want to compile the whole thing with g++?  I've typically seen extern "C" in C++ code when you are building a .dll and want to link to it without having to know the mangled name.

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus: Also take a look at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus: You cannot use C++ features in a header file that's intended to be processed by a C compiler (unless you hide them inside an `#ifndef __cplusplus ... #endif`).

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus: "What do you mean link?" - I fear we have a problem here... check out the `-c` option in the GCC manuals, and what "linking" is about. Otherwise, no answer you could get here will make sense.

Comment: @JoshPetitt: In this case, any kind of shared library (`.so`, `.dll`, etc.). Because this is GCC, I think that it is probably Linux, and if it isen't, GCC on other platforms still uses `.so`. (Mac uses it anyway, on Windows you need a Cygwin-like layer).

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be `ifdef __cplusplus`?

Answer (score 3):

call it in C using

```
func(/* put arguments here */);
```

By saying extern "C" you are asking the compiler not to mangle your names.  Otherwise, C++ compiler would tend to mangle them (i.e. add additional symbols to make them unique) before the linker.

You'll also want to make sure you have setup to use C calling convention.

Comment: Being horribly picky, it disables *c++* mangling, not *all* mangling (c uses mangling in some cases). http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/05/25/10310148.aspx

Comment: @BoBTFish :-) yeah that's why I said "asking" the compiler.  +1 for the clarification and hyperlink.

Answer (score 1):

```
//header file included from both C and C++ files

#ifndef __cplusplus
#include <stdbool.h> // for C99 type bool
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void func(bool first, float min, float* state[6], float* err[6][6]);

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // extern "C"
#endif
```

```
// cpp file
#include "the_above_header.h"
#include <vector>

extern "C" void func(bool first, float min, float* state[6], float* err[6][6]);
{
    //uses vectors and classes and other C++ constructs
}

// c file
#include "the_above_header.h"

int main() {
    bool b;
    float f;
    float *s[6];
    float *err[6][6];
    func(b,f,s,err);
}
```