# Call C++ functions containing STL data types from C

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I have a function in C++ that uses data types like `vector` and `map` from STL. Here is some sample code:

**mylib.cpp**

```
#include "mylib.h"
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

    int summation(int n) {
    vector<int> numbers;
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <=n; i++) 
        numbers.push_back(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < numbers.size(); j++)
        sum += numbers[j];

    return sum;
    }
```

I created a header file as follows:

**mylib.h**

```
#ifdef _cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
extern int summation(int n);
#ifdef _cplusplus
};
#endif
```

The C++ file was compiled into the obejct code using the command

```
g++ -o mylib.o -c mylib.cpp
```

Then, I wrote a C program in order to use the function `summation` from it.

**main.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "mylib.h"

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d", summation(n));
    return 0;
}
```

Now, when I compile the C file above using **gcc**,

```
gcc main.c mylib.o
```

I get the following error

```
/tmp/ccAMN2ld.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `summation'
mylib.o: In function `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int const&)':
mylib.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPiS1_EERKi[_ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPiS1_EERKi]+0x26e): undefined reference to `__cxa_begin_catch'
mylib.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPiS1_EERKi[_ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPiS1_EERKi]+0x2d7): undefined reference to `__cxa_rethrow'
mylib.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPiS1_EERKi[_ZNSt6vectorIiSaIiEE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPiS1_EERKi]+0x2df): undefined reference to `__cxa_end_catch'
mylib.o: In function `std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_check_len(unsigned long, char const*) const':
mylib.cpp:(.text._ZNKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE12_M_check_lenEmPKc[_ZNKSt6vectorIiSaIiEE12_M_check_lenEmPKc]+0x5b): undefined reference to `std::__throw_length_error(char const*)'
mylib.o: In function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::deallocate(int*, unsigned long)':
mylib.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE10deallocateEPim[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE10deallocateEPim]+0x1c): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
mylib.o: In function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*)':
mylib.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE8allocateEmPKv[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE8allocateEmPKv]+0x2c): undefined reference to `std::__throw_bad_alloc()'
mylib.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE8allocateEmPKv[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIiE8allocateEmPKv]+0x3c): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
mylib.o:(.eh_frame+0x4b): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It is imperative that I use gcc to compile the C file. Is there a way to make it work?

I tried looking for solution and stumbled upon the links below,

[How to call C++ function from C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744181/how-to-call-c-function-from-c)

[Elegantly call C++ from C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281441/elegantly-call-c-from-c)

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/8997/

but couldn't find a solution to my problem.

Comment: Why would a c compiler know how to compile c++ components. Maybe you need to compile the c++ component fully then link the binaries.

Comment: This question looks like a dupe of those you linked to. The answers describe general possible solutions, and you need to implement them in your concrete code, that's all.

Comment: Use `g++` to link the code (not `gcc` — the program is a C++ program because it has some C++ in it).  It is usually better to use `g++` to compile the file containing `main()` since that has special properties in C++ (unlike in C), though you may get away with using a C compiler to create the object file holding `main()`.

Comment: @ForceBru In those questions, STL components haven't been used. I got the error I mentioned when I tried those approaches. However, it worked for programs that don't contain STL components but not for the ones containing them.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Compiling with `g++` works. However, as I mentioned that it is really important that I use `gcc` for the file containing the `main` function. I was hoping there was a way around.

Comment: You can try compiling `main.c` to `main.o` with `gcc`, then linking with `g++ -o program main.o mylib.o` — you may be lucky and get away with that. Failing that, create `cpp-main.cpp` containing `extern "C" int c_main(); int main() { return c_main(); }` (or `extern "C" int c_main(int argc, char **argv); int main(int argc, char **argv) { return c_main(argc, argv); }`) and compile that with `g++`. In the existing `main.c`, change the function to `int c_main(void) { …your code… }` (or the equivalent with arguments), not forgetting to declare the function (since it is no longer called `main()`).

Comment: The crucial point is to link the program with `g++` so that you get the correct C++ libraries linked.  Linking with `gcc` will be a painful exercise by comparison.  In case of doubt, try using `g++ -v` and `gcc -v` to do the different linking operations, and see how much difference there is in the commands invoked to do the linking.

Comment: This is same question. Maybe help you.
[See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580968/c-and-c-linkage-with-extern-c)

Comment: You need to use `extern "C"` in `mylib.h` **and** the `mylib.cpp` file. Also link against the `C++` runtime library `-lstdc++` (I think)

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903005/how-to-mix-c-and-c-correctly/31903685#31903685

Comment: In fact possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31903005/how-to-mix-c-and-c-correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile the C file by itself with the C compiler:

```
gcc -c cfile.c
```

then link all the files with the C++ compiler:

```
g++ -o a.out main.o cfile.o mylib.o
```

Note that you *must* compile the file with the `main` function with the C++ compiler.  Any other files can be compiled with either, though you need `extern "C"` declarations to be able to call C code from C++ or create C++ functions that can be called from C

Answer (score 0):

I have build all the file in g++, am not getting linking error. can you build all the source file to gcc or g++.